# Problems with replacing /e modifier to preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I am having some trouble with replacing preg_replace with /e modifier to preg_replace_callback in this function:

```
    private function parseFunctions() {
    // replaces includes ( {include file="..."} )
    while( preg_match( "/" .$this->leftDelimiterF ."include file=\"(.*)\.(.*)\""
                       .$this->rightDelimiterF ."/isUe", $this->template) )
    {
        $this->template = preg_replace( "/" .$this->leftDelimiterF ."include file=\"(.*)\.(.*)\""
                                        .$this->rightDelimiterF."/isUe",
                                        "file_get_contents(\$this->templateDir.'\\1'.'.'.'\\2')",
                                        $this->template );
    }


    // deletes comments from the template files
    $this->template = preg_replace( "/" .$this->leftDelimiterC ."(.*)" .$this->rightDelimiterC ."/isUe",
                                    "", $this->template );
    }
```

Can you help me with this?

EDIT:

I managed to fix the second one, but the other

```
{
        $this->template = preg_replace_callback( "/" .$this->leftDelimiterF ."include file=\"(.*)\.(.*)\""
                                        .$this->rightDelimiterF."/isU",
                                        function(){$replacement="file_get_contents(\$this->templateDir.'\\1'.'.'.'\\2')";
                                        return $replacement;},
                                        $this->template );
    }
```

did not work.
I got following error message:

file_get_contents($this->templateDir.'\1'.'.'.'\2')
file_get_contents($this->templateDir.'\1'.'.'.'\2') file_get_contents($this->templateDir.'\1'.'.'.'\2')
file_get_contents($this->templateDir.'\1'.'.'.'\2') file_get_contents($this->templateDir.'\1'.'.'.'\2') file_get_contents($this->templateDir.'\1'.'.'.'\2')

I am still relatively new to php so i am not sure how to handle this issue.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing, why do you replace in the while and then inside the loop itself. Just one of them should be enough.

Comment: I'm not sure either. I didn't write it originally, I only have to deal with it

Comment: So could you at least give a better explanation of what the problem is?

Comment: The Problem is, that the /e modifier is depricated (preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead). I am trying to correct some problems with the code and these are left...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I understood what you are trying to do.
The callback function should receive an array of all the matches or a single match (depending on what was found).
So it would look something like this:

`$this->template = preg_replace_callback( "/" .$this->leftDelimiterF ."include file=\"(.*)\.(.*)\"".$this->rightDelimiterF."/isU",
function($match){
    $replacement="file_get_contents(\$this->match.'\\1'.'.'.'\\2')";
    return $replacement;},
this->template );`

If you need some outside variable inside the anonymous function then declare the callback function as
`function($match) use ($varname)`

Comment: Works just fine, until the site tries to load a template file. Then I get the error message:                                          file_get_contents($this->match.'\1'.'.'.'\2')
file_get_contents($this->match.'\1'.'.'.'\2') file_get_contents($this->match.'\1'.'.'.'\2')
file_get_contents($this->match.'\1'.'.'.'\2') file_get_contents($this->match.'\1'.'.'.'\2') file_get_contents($this->match.'\1'.'.'.'\2')

Comment: what does "load a template" mean?

Comment: All the html stuff is included in .tpl files.                                                        {include file="assideleft.tpl"}  
            {include file="middlecontent.tpl"}
            {include file="assideright.tpl"} The function replaces this with the content of the .tpl files

Comment: sorry, I got it now.
Instead of `function($match)` do 'function($matches)` and inside instead of `\\1` and `\\2` try `$match[0]` and `match[1]` accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 different variables `$match` and `$matches`. Here is a working code:

```
$this->template = preg_replace_callback(
    "/".$this->leftDelimiterF.'include file="([^"]+)"'.$this->rightDelimiterF."/isU",
     function($match){
         $replacement = "file_get_contents(\$this->templateDir.$match[1])";
         return $replacement;
     },
$this->template );
```

Comment: I tried it out and at least I get a whole new error message: Catchable fatal error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\mxframework\mxsframework\data\system\classes\view\cl_template.php on line 288

Comment: I added a little change:                                                                              {
        $this->template = preg_replace_callback(
    "/".$this->leftDelimiterF.'include file="([^"]+)"'.$this->rightDelimiterF."/isU",
     function($match){
         $replacement = "file_get_contents(\'$this->templateDir'.$match[1])";
         return $replacement;
     },
$this->template );
    }                                                                                                      error Message is now: file_get_contents(\'templates/officelook2013/tplfiles/'.header.tpl)

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->template = preg_replace_callback("/" .$this->leftDelimiterF ."include file=\"(.*)\.(.*)\""
     .$this->rightDelimiterF."/isU", 
     function ($m) { return file_get_contents($this->templateDir.$m[1].'.'.$m[2]);}, 
     $this->template);
```

Comment: Can you provide a short explanation of your code? Thanks!